# Removing key value pair from list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have below list of dictionaries:

```
>>> d={}
>>> d['primary info']={"name":"Mark","age":22,"Id":1234}
>>> d['secondary info']={"location":"Pune"}
```

Now dictionary `d` has list as following:

```
{'secondary info': {'location': 'Pune'}, 'primary info': {'age': 22, 'Id': 1234, 'name': 'Mark'}}
```

1. How can I remove `age` key-value pair from `primary info`?
2. How can I update value of `Id` in `primary info`?

Comment: 1. `del d['primary info']['age']`, 2. `d['primary info']['Id'] = <the new id>`

Answer (score 1):

To remove a `key, value` pair, you can use [`del`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement):

```
>>> d = {"bob": "fish", "cat": "dog"}
>>> del d["cat"]
>>> d
{'bob': 'fish'}
```

---

As for the second part, you need to get the value of the key `"primary info"` (another `dictionary) and then access the`"Id"` value of this, and update it:

```
d["primary info"]["Id"] = 4321
```

which I can confirm, updates the value:

```
{..., 'primary info': {'Id': 4321, 'name': ...}, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a key or value from `dict` you can use `del`. For more info regarding `del` go to this [link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/del-python)

You can solve your problem like this..

```
d={}
d['primary info']={"name":"Mark","age":22,"Id":1234}
d['secondary info']={"location":"Pune"}

del d['primary info']['age'] # deleting

d['primary info']['Id'] = 177 # updating

print(d)

# Output

{'primary info': {'Id': 177, 'name': 'Mark'}, 'secondary info': {'location': 'Pune'}}
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'secondary info': {'location': 'Pune'}, 'primary info': {'age': 22, 'Id': 1234, 'name': 'Mark'}}
new_id = 2344
new_d = {a:{c:new_id if c == "Id" else d for c, d in b.items() if c != 'age'} for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'primary info': {'Id': 2344, 'name': 'Mark'}, 'secondary info': {'location': 'Pune'}}
```

Or, you can use recursion for a more robust solution:

```
def update(d, new_id, delemeter='age'):
    if all(not isinstance(b, dict) for a, b in d.items()):
       return {a:new_id if a == "Id" else b for a, b in d.items() if a != delemeter}
    final_data = {a:update(b, new_id, delemeter=delemeter) for a, b in d.items()}
    return final_data
```

Output:

```
{'primary info': {'Id': 2344, 'name': 'Mark'}, 'secondary info': {'location': 'Pune'}}
```